# remove www URL site

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

I created a rule and it works fine (removes www from the url), except I have multiple domains pointing to the same source. How can apply this rule to specific address only, If I have 2 domains abc1.com and abc2.com right now, if I enter abc2.com it redirects to abc1.com

what am I missing?, thank you

```
<rule name="Remove www">
      <match url="(.*)" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^abc1\.com$" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="http://abc1.com/{R:1}" />
    </rule>
```

Comment: You want the `www` to removed for all your websites or only `abc1.com`?

Comment: for both websites, but if you can show me how to do it for one too, that would be perfect, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the `www` for all websites you have binded, you can use:

```
<rule name="Remove www">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(.*)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

What it does: if the url does start with `www.`, it redirects the request to whatever is after `www.` (`http://{C:1}/{R:0}`).

If you want to only match your 2 websites `abc1.com` and `abc2.com`, you can use:

```
<rule name="Remove www">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www\.(abc[1|2]\.com)$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://{C:1}/{R:0}" />
</rule>
```

(to match only `abc1.com`, replace `pattern="^www\.(abc[1|2]\.com)$"` with `pattern="^www\.(abc1\.com)$"`)

Comment: works, thanks so much, if it is not too hard, can you show me how would you do it for just one website too?

Comment: @Ben I have added the code in my answer, let me know if it helps!

Comment: Thanks, Do you know a good link that describes how rule works, conditions, pattern? pls correct me if I am wrong, if pattern is a match it executes the action? so if I enter abc1.com the action is not been executed b/c I didn't enter 'www' at the beginning? Also for example, if I had 10 domains, and I wanted the 2 websites abc1,abc2 to have www removed, can I add the patten regular expression you created to the match url? instead of".*"? thanks again!

Comment: A good link to read about this module is: http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite `if pattern is a match it executes the action?` Yes, unless you specify the option `negate="true"`. `url=".*"` is used only for what's after `www.domain.com/`, this is why in your case, you have to use the conditions.